# How to use the "watch" command with SSH

Tags: linux, bash, ssh, monitoring, watch

I have a script that monitors a specific server, giving me the disk usage, CPU usage, etc. I am using 2 Ubuntu VMs: I run the script on the server using SSH (`ssh user@ip < script.sh` from the first VM), and I want to make it show values in real time, so I tried 2 approaches I found on here:

### 1. `while` loop with `clear`

The first approach is using a while loop with "clear" to make the script run multiple times, giving new values every time and clearing the previous output like so:

```sh
while true
do
      clear; 
      # bunch of code
done
```

The problem here is that it doesn't clear the terminal, it just keeps printing the new results one after another.

### 2. `watch`

The second approach uses `watch`:

```sh
watch -n 1 Script.sh
```

This works fine on the local machine (to monitor the current machine where the script is), but I can't find a way to make it run via SSH. Something like

```sh
ssh user@ip < 'watch -n 1 script.sh'
```

works in principle, but requires that the script be present on the server, which I want to avoid. Is there any way to run `watch` for the remote execution (via SSH) of a script that is present on the local machine?

Answer (score 2):

For your second approach (using `watch`), what you can do instead is to run `watch` locally (from within the first VM) with an SSH command and piped-in script like this:

```
watch -n 1 'ssh user@ip < script.sh'
```

The drawback of this is that it will reconnect in each `watch` iteration (i.e., once a second), which some server configurations might not allow. See [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/746487/1164065) for how to let SSH re-use the same connection for serial `ssh` runs.

But if what you want to do is to monitor servers, what I really recommend is to use a monitoring system like 'telegraf'.

Comment: i already try it man but it didn't work  :( . thank's btw .

Comment: @yacineR There command as originally written in the answer was missing quotes around `ssh user@ip < script.sh` - try again with the quotes, it should work.